# Is the Mailchimp API available in other languages?

Tags: internationalization, mailchimp

I'm using the Mailchimp API in combination with PHP and jQuery to provide the subscribing/unsubscribing-actions on a website via Ajax.
On errors with user data you get useful messages like "Invalid Email Address", "test@example.com is already subscribed to list x. Click here to update your profile." or "There is no record of "test@example.com" in the database".

For sure I want to keep theses messages, but is there a way I can get them in other languages (in particular in German)? How would I achieve this? I wasn't able to find anything about in the Mailchimp docs.
I wouldn't like to translate them myself...

Comment: belongs on webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using mailchimp for a while and I believe there is no way to get internationalization trough their API.

You should threat errors by yourself and customize the messages.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mailchimp-api-discuss/browse_thread/thread/32e0199e8dce7716?pli=1) in the API discussion group, this is actually a function of the list itself, and isn't handled by the API. If what you're asking about is being able to *change* the language to something from your end, it looks like that may not be supported.